# git - find the change history of particular file by one user in oneline

Tags: git

How to find the change history of particular file by one user in oneline
I am looking for some single command which does the following 3

```
git log --author=author
git log --pretty=oneline
git log -p pom.xml
```

I just want the SHAID, author and commit message of a particular file in one line

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misunderstood your requirements early; this particular format from `--pretty=format` will give you what you require.

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %an %s' --author=gnavin -z -- pom.xml
```

[`-z` replaces newlines with `NUL`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), so you can get all the results on one line.  It's up to you to deal with the `NUL` characters, though.

Comment: It didn't produce the output in one line. I just want the SHAID, author and commit message of a particular file in one line

Comment: Awesome it works. Thanks. I was trying similar to this     git log --format='%H %an %s' -p -- pom.xml